# Using jQuery on ajax response triggers additional network requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a small script that takes a bunch of links from a page, fetches them and scours the results for some data.
E.g. like this:

```js
let listLinks = $('.item a');

listLinks.each(function() {
    let url = this.href;

    fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(function(html) {
        let name = $('#title h1', html);
    })
});
```

My problem is the fact that once we reach selector on the response the network tab in my browser's dev-tools lights up with requests for a ton of resources, as if something (jquery?) is just loading the entire page!

What the hell is going on here?

I don't want to load the entire page(resources and all), I just want to take a bunch of text from the html response!

**Edit:** After some more scrutiny, I discovered it only makes network requests for any images on the ajaxed page, but not scripts or stylesheets.

It does not make these requests if I try to process the html in another way - say, call `.indexOf()` on it. Only if I decide to traverse it via jquery.

**Edit2:** Poking around in dev tools, the network tab has an "initiator" column. It says this is the initiator for the requests: [github code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js#L46). I don't know what to make of that however...

P.S. [Inb4 "just regex it".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: `I don't want to load the entire page, I just want to take a bunch of text from the html response!` Unfortunately that's not how AJAX works. When you make a request you will receive the ***entire*** response back. In this case you then need to dissect that response to get only the relevant data you want. This is the same way jQuery's `load()` method works. If you want to change this behaviour, amend the endpoints you call to only return the relevant HTML.

Comment: By "the entire page" I meant also all linked resources such as images and scripts. Although now, under scrutiny, I noticed something else relevant - it requests only images(not scripts or stylesheets). I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the cause:

My code above(relevant line):
`$('#title h1', html)`
is equivalent to
`$(html).find('#title h1')`

And `$(html)` essentially [creates DOM elements](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). Actual, literal DOM objects.

When you create an `<img>` element(which the HTML I parse contains), the browser automatically issues a network request.
Relevant StackOverflow question:
[Set img src without issuing a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134803/set-img-src-without-issuing-a-request)

With the code in the question the created DOM elements are still associated with the current document(as noted [here](https://www.xfive.co/blog/how-to-parse-html-response-without-loading-any-images/)), therefore the browser automatically makes a request for new `<img>`s it doesn't have yet.
The correct solution is to create a separate document, e.g.

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
let name = $('#title h1', doc);
```

No network requests go out in this case.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ae612pxv/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `fetch`. Use `jQuery.AJAX`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'URL',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'HTML',
  success: function(responseHTML) {
    console.log(responseHTML);
  } 
});
```

Comment: This is logically identical to what the OP already has and will make no difference to the issue